# How do I find a combination of a letter a number in a VBA string?

Tags: regex, string, vba

I'd like to check if in a string (with `InStr`?) the combination of a single alphabetical letter and a number is to be found. In particular the letter can only be:

"R" or "B" or "G" or "Y"

While the numbers can go from 1 to 9.

```
Examples given:

R1 is legal
Y6 is legal
A2 is not legal
G10 is not legal
```

In this string only one instance of this combination can be found, and it is marked by an underscore "_" at the beginning. It can also happen that this combination is nowhere to be found.

I would like to avoid the trivial solution (which brings a lot of calculations that I don't need in my program) of a series of `Or`, or an incredibly long `Select Case`.

Is there any way to use a custom variable or wildcards here?

Comment: use `RegEx` , it's fits your case

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit? I have no idea what that is

Comment: Do you mean you have a string like `I have R1 and G9 and R101 A2222 substrings` and you want to receive a collection/array containing `R1` and `G9` only? Or just return `True`/`False` if a string contains your pattern?

Comment: For `RegEx`, you may check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/1050927

Comment: I added some info in the question. I can have `blahblahblah_R1.blah` and I would like to get `R1` as a return.

Comment: You can also use Like operator to do evaluation for ex. `yourValue Like "_[RBGY]#"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex to get the value you are looking for:

```
_([YRGB]\d)(?!\d)
```

Here, `_` will find an underscore, then `([YRGB]\d)` will match and capture a letter from the `[YRGB]` character class (`Y`, `R`, `G` or `B`) and any digit (`\d`) that is not followed with another digit (`(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location).

Or with a word boundary (`\b`, it will require a char other than a letter/digit or `_` right after the digit) at the end:

```
_([YRGB]\d)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/brD3F6/1). The result is the substring captured into Group 1.

Sample VBA code:

```
Sub DemoFn()
Dim re As RegExp
Dim s As String, res As String
Dim colMatch As MatchCollection, objMatch As Match

s = "blahblahblah_R1.blah"
Set re = New RegExp
With re
  .pattern = "_([YRGB]\d)(?!\d)"
  .Global = False
  .MultiLine = False
End With

Set colMatch = re.Execute(s)
For Each objMatch In colMatch
  res = objMatch.SubMatches.Item(0)
Next
Debug.Print res
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the VBA Like Operator:

```
Sub PatternMatching
    If (("G6" Like "[YRGB][1-9]") = True) Then
        Msgbox("this is a match")
    End If
End Sub
```